# Why is every Boolean ring regular?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, boolean-ring

*I answered my own question. As usual, I was overthinking. In writing this up, I figured it out, so thought I'd keep it as a Q&A, seeing as though I couldn't find it anywhere.*

### The Question:

> Show that every Boolean ring is regular.

### The Details:

> **Definition:** A ring $R$ is *Boolean* if $a^2=a$ for all $a\in R$.

All Boolean rings are commutative.

> **Definition:** An element $x$ in a ring $R$ is *regular* if there exists a $y\in R$ such that $x=xyx$.  We call $R$ *regular* if all its elements are regular.

### Thoughts:

Let $R$ be Boolean, $a,b\in R$. Then

$$aabb=a^2b^2=ab=(ab)^2=abab.$$

What now?

### Further Context:

I wrote my undergraduate dissertation on inverse semigroups, which are regular semigroups whose idempotents commute. This ought to be something I can answer myself.  I gave it a while but . . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x\in R$ for a Boolean ring $R$. We have

$$\begin{align}
x&=x^2\, \text{(Boolean)}\\
&=xx\, \text{(Indices)}\\
&=xx^2\, \text{(Boolean)}\\
&=x\color{red}{x}x\, \text{(Indices)}.
\end{align}$$

So just let $y=\color{red}{x}$.

Comment: Any reason for the downvote?